# How to create a macro to refresh a worksheet to its original state?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet full of data and am trying to create a macro that I can run which will restore the sheet back to its original state (With all of the original data in place). None of the info is linked to other worksheets and it is not protected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to achieve the equivalent of closing the workbook (without saving) and re-opening the workbook - but just for one sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Let's says that you have a file called **Original.xlsx** where the original data is saved, you could then use the following code to open it and transfer the values.

I'm using the term transfer here because it's **not a copy-paste**, you are simply **passing on the values** using VBA instead of copy-pasting which can be slower when you have a lot of data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Transfer_data()

    Dim Orig As Workbook, DataRange As Range
    Set Orig = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\Original.xlsx")
    Set DataRange = Orig.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    Dim TopLeftRow As Long, TopLeftColumn As Long, BottomRightRow As Long, BottomRightColumn As Long
    TopLeftRow = DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Row
    TopLeftColumn = DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Column
    BottomRightRow = DataRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    BottomRightColumn = DataRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'We clear the content, but not the formattting
    MySheet.Cells.ClearContent

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = MySheet.Range(MySheet.Cells(TopLeftRow, TopLeftColumn), MySheet.Cells(BottomRightRow, BottomRightColumn))

    MyRange.Value2 = DataRange.Value2

    Orig.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

I'm assuming that your dataset is relatively large, so that's why you would need to put it in a separate file, but you could also modify this code to make the same thing, but using another sheet inside your workbook instead of opening another workbook.